# node process doesn't exit after firebase once

Tags: node.js, firebase

Using node.js with the npm firebase.

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
var blahFirebase = new firebase('https://myfirebase.firebaseIO.com/blah');
blahFirebase.once('value', function (snapshot) {
    //
});
```

Why does node not exit when it is done reading the data?

Comment: That 3rd line is suppose to be `once` or `on`?

Comment: It is supposed to be once.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update**

Note that this is no longer applicable. Node.js will no longer hang when using once(), although it will be held open as long as there are active listeners subscribed to the remote server.

**Original**

The Firebase process opens sockets to the server and establishes listeners for incoming data on those connections. Just like a node web server, awaiting incoming HTTP connections, this holds the process open.

To end the process, you can simply utilize process.exit() from inside the callback:

```
blahFirebase.once('value', function (snapshot) {
    //
    process.exit();
});
```

Comment: I am using Node.js and Firebase to develop an AWS lambda. Call lambda would fail if I call process.exit(), but if I do nothing, it will timeout. database.goOffline() doesn't work. Any better solution?

Comment: @syshen in Lambda you should call `context.succeed()` instead.

Comment: with `process.exit()` the process ends but I don't get data written to the database. Have anyone ran into this problem?

Comment: use firebase.delete() instead. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.app.App#delete

Comment: Calling firebase.database().goOffline() or firebase.app().delete(). https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js

Answer (score 25):

In the new Firebase API you should use [firebase.app.App.delete()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.app.App#delete) to free the resources its holding. For example:

```
var app = firebase.initializeApp({ ... });
var db = firebase.database();

// Do something

app.delete(); // Release resources
```

Do not use `process.exit()` since it will stop the entire process (which is not what you would usually want).

Comment: You can also use
    `var firebase = require("firebase")
    firebase.app('[DEFAULT]').delete()`

Comment: But how I can stop to listening an ```.on('value', function () {})```? I have a search form, and I have to stop the listening to start another with different parameters.

Comment: Using ```app.delete()``` doesn't exit my process after signing in and signing out. Any luck with this?

Here is my minimal example: https://gist.github.com/juriejan/2134fc2569e56a24fc9b886f1f156198

Comment: If you used `firebase.auth()`, you may need to log out first, too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65660764/198219

Answer (score 13):

My case is using firebase admin,

```
const  admin = require('firebase-admin');
```

and I can end node process by

```
return admin.app().delete();
```

Comment: If it doesn't work, try changing when you're placing it this line of code (towards the end)

Answer (score -1):

```
setTimeout(()=> {
    process.exit(1);
}, 1000);
```

Dunno why, but solved the problem.