# Closing a firebase connection in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, firebase

I'm trying to create a simple node.JS command-line script to interact with Firebase using their Javascript API. I want the tool to close the Firebase connection and terminate once it has finished it's interaction.

Here is some sample code showing what I am trying to achieve:

```js
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var myRootRef = new Firebase('https://myprojectname.firebaseIO-demo.com/');
myRootRef.set('It's working!');
```

One possible solution would be adding a callback and calling process.exit():

```js
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var myRootRef = new Firebase('https://myprojectname.firebaseIO-demo.com/');
myRootRef.set("It's working!", function() { 
    process.exit(0); 
});
```

However, I would love to have a more elegant solution than forcing the process to terminate with process.exit().

Any ideas?

Comment: There is currently no documented way to terminate a Firebase connection.

Comment: Thanks, is there any undocumented way to do so? It's okay even if the code will break in the future...

Comment: @Anant When is Firebase going to fix this? It would be really nice not to have to use process.exit(0) to terminate a node process in which we have done firebase work.

Comment: this issue is ridiculous indeed; and even more ridiculous is fact that it has not been fixed during the last 3 years.

Answer (score 9):

i'm not keen on forcing disconnect with `process.exit(0)` either.. as i only require data persistence (not real-time features) i use the [REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest-api-quickstart.html).. I find plain HTTPS twice as fast as the official firebase npm module..

```
var https = require("https"),
    someData = { some: "data" };

var req = https.request({ 
    hostname: "myprojectname.firebaseio.com", 
    method: "POST", 
    path: "/.json"
});
req.end(JSON.stringify(someData));
```

Answer (score 3):

This can probably be solved with `firebase.database().goOffline()`. Got this from another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37858899

Comment: This only works in the case of `const db = firebase.database(); db.goOffline();`. Any operation on the db itself causes the process to hang open.

Answer (score 2):

There are several steps required to properly stop the Firebase JS SDK, so that the Node.js process can terminate normally without forcibly interrupting it with `process.exit()`:

- You need to cancel any asynchronous listeners (like "on data change" events) that you set up
- Call `firebase.database().goOffline()`
- If you used `firebase.auth()` you need to call `firebase.auth().signOut()`
- Finally, you also need to destroy the Firebase application by calling `app.delete()`

I've tested this with Node.js version 10 and Firebase JS SDK version 8.

Source: https://blog.famzah.net/2021/01/11/properly-stop-a-firebase-app-in-node-js/