# Process timeout | Amazon Lambda to Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, aws-lambda

i've written code in node.js and my data is on Firebase. The problem i'm facing is that my code never exits. I've done it like this one [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325775/amazon-lambda-to-firebase/37858899#comment64277316_37858899)

The problem is that firebase referance/listener never become null and therefore my function never exits. I tried using `firebase.database().goOffline()` but it didn't work.

On my local machine i forcefully stopped the process using `process.exit(0)`, but when i deployed my code on AWS lambda, it doesn't return any response/call back and exits (giving error message "**Process exited before completing request**")

I also added wait of 5-10 seconds after invoking callback in lambda and then forcefully exited the process, but it didn't help either.

How to fix this issue? Please help.

Answer (score 9):

Your going through crisis that any new `lambda` user has gone.

As suggested, you can use `context.done` for stopping.
**However**, this is not recommended as this is only possible due to historic runtime versions of nodejs.

---

### why this timeout happens?

Your lambda may get to the last line of your code and still keep running. Well, it is actually waiting for something - for the event loop to be empty.

### what this means?

In nodejs, when you make an async operation and register a callback function to be executed once the operation is done, the registration sort of happens in the event loop.

In one line, it's the event loop that knows which callback function to execute when an async operation ends. But that's to another thread :)

---

### back to Lambda

Given the above information, it follows that lambda **should not** halt before empty event loop is reached - as this means some follow-up procedure **will not** execute after some async operation returns.

What if you still need to halt the execution manually? regardless of the event loop status?
At the beginning of the function, execute:

```
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false
```

And then use the third parameter you get in the handler signature. Which is the `callback`.

### the callback parameter

It is a function which you call when you want to end the execution.

If you call it with no parameters, or with the first parameter as null and text as second parameter - it is considered as a successful invocation.

To fail the lambda execution, you can call the callback function with some non-null value as the first parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Add this line at the beginning of your handler function and then you should be able to use the callback without issue:

```
function handler (event, context, callback) {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false // Add this line
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting `callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` to `false` should only be your last resort if nothing else works for you, as this might introduce worse bugs than the problem you're trying to solve here.

This is what I do instead to ensure every call has firebase initialized, and deleted before exiting.

```
// handlerWithFirebase.js

const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const config = require("./config.json");

function initialize() {
  return admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(config),
    databaseURL: "https://<your_app>.firebaseio.com",
  });
}

function handlerWithFirebase(func) {
  return (event, context, callback) => {
    const firebase = initialize();
    let _callback = (error, result) => {
      firebase.delete();
      callback(error, result);
    }
    // passing firebase into your handler here is optional
    func(event, context, _callback, firebase /*optional*/);
  }
}

module.exports = handlerWithFirebase;
```

And then in my lambda handler code

```
// myHandler.js

const handlerWithFirebase = require("../firebase/handler");

module.exports.handler = handlerWithFirebase(
(event, context, callback, firebase) => {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `callback`funciton and then `process.exit(0)` didn't help in my case. `goOffline()` method of `firebase` didn't help either.

I fixed the issue calling `context.done(error, response)` (instead of callback method). Now, my code is working.

Still, if any one have better solution, kindly post here. It may help some one else :)

Comment: goOffline() and callback() din't work for me either. I could see the response in log output but result was timeout. It started working on using context.done(err, rest). I am not sure about the support from aws, it gives me a waring that context.done() is deprecated in nodejs4.3

Comment: oh.. thanks sanjeev, i'll check my code as well as i'm using nodejs4.3.. I'm new to Node.js, can you kindly tell me, which compiler or tool you're using? @sanjeev