# Initialize Firebase inside AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, aws-lambda

I installed only `"firebase-auth"` `"firebase-app"` modules inside AWS lambda because the .zip file has to be smaller then 10mb.

And this is my code inside AWS lambda.

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  var config = {
    apiKey: "lnlnnl",
    authDomain: "lfirjlkje.baseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://kjhjkh.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "jhkhjh-88eaf",
    storageBucket: "hj.hjappspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "977997"
  };

  if(firebase.apps.length == 0) {
     firebase.initializeApp(config);
  } 
    };
```

I have `firebase.apps` undefined and `firebase.initializeApp` undefined.

any ideas what is wrong ?

Comment: You must have the firebase node_module on your deployment package to have this dependency working.

Comment: I have the dependency installed in aws.
if I console.log(firebase); I have the function there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Amazon Lambda to Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325775/amazon-lambda-to-firebase)