# How to close firebase connection in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is a simple example how I am using firebase:

```
let firebase = require('firebase');
firebase.initializeApp({
  serviceAccount: './config/firebase.json',
  databaseURL: 'https://thenameofhedatabase.firebaseio.com'
});

let db = firebase.database();
...
...
```

The point is that after all code execution the `db` object holds the node.js session. I do not want to call `process.exit(0)`. So, what is the right way to close or dispose the `db` object of the firebase?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870587/closing-a-firebase-connection-in-node-js

Comment: Question is almost the same, but it doesn't have any answers.

Comment: there is no way to close the connection, or at least the docs don't expose it. the only similar thing is `db.goOffline()`, but I don't think that will work, and you probably prefer to just `process.exit(0)`.

Comment: You are right, ```db.goOffline()``` doesn't work.

Answer (score 11):

This is something that has been [fixed in the version 3.4.1 of the JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#3.4.1).

`firebase.database().goOffline()` now properly releases the database so the Node.js process can exit.

Comment: This is still happening for me in 4.0.0, but firebase.database().goOffline() fixed it. Thanks!