# Not sure why node is continuously running

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-cloud-firestore

I can't figure out why this app keeps running. I've tried using the **why-is-node-running** package but I'm not perfectly sure how to read the output properly. Here's the first output of it:

```
There are 30 handle(s) keeping the process running
    # TCPWRAP
    /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:269 - socket = tls.connect(parseSslOptions(family, options));
    /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:29  - makeConnection(family, options, cancellationToken, (err, socket) => {
    /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/monitor.js:182       - connect(monitor.connectOptions, monitor[kCancellationToken], (err, conn) => {
    /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/monitor.js:206       - checkServer(monitor, e0 => {
    /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/monitor.js:92        - monitorServer(this);
```

My guess is it has something to do with MongoDB not closing properly. Although, when I removed all of the other functions between opening the client and closing it, it opened and closed perfectly.

Adding `process.exit()` at the end closes program properly, but I'd like to figure out why it isn't closing.

A summary of the app is that it is getting data from MongoDB, cleaning it, and then writing it into Firestore - so a lot of async actions going on, but I didn't see Firestore-related stuff pop up in the why-is-node-running logs.

```
const GrabStuffFromDBToCalculate = require("./helpers/GrabStuffFromDBToCalculate");
const SendToFirestore = require("./helpers/SendToFirestore");
const log = require("why-is-node-running");
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
require("dotenv").config();

const main = async () => {
  try {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
    const collection = await client.db("test").collection("testcollection");
    const trip_object = await GrabStuffFromDBToCalculate(collection);
    SendToFirestore(trip_object);
    client.close();
    log(); // "There are 30 handle(s) keeping the process running including node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:269 - socket = tls.connect(parseSslOptions(family, options));"
    // process.exit() // this closes everything but I'd rather not have to use this
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    client.close();
  }
};

const runAsync = async () => {
  await main(); // this exists because I'm usually running multiple main() functions
};

runAsync();
```

SendToFirestore code:

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
const firebaseConfig = require("../config");

module.exports = SendToFirestore = trip_object => {
  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  }
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  db.doc(`hello/${object._id}`).set({
    objectid:object._id
  });
};
```

GrabStuffFromDBToCalculate code (way simplified):

```
module.exports = GrabStuffFromDBToCalculate = async collection => {
  const cursor = await collection
    .aggregate([

        // does a bunch of stuff here

    ])
    .toArray();
  const newObj = cursor[0];
  return newObj;
};
```

Comment: It seems like there more to see such as the code for `SendToFirestore()` and `GrabStuffFromDBToCalculate()`.  Also, you should call `log()` AFTER you `await client.close()` so you're sure that is complete before `log()` lists the open handles.

Comment: You could try forcing the close with `client.close(true)`. I've used it before when the mongo client has kept the process alive but I haven't taken the time to investigate why the client doesn't close without it.

Comment: Also, doesn't `log()` show you the ACTUAL handles that are still open?  Can you share that output with us?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the complete, minimal code that exhibits the problem.  What you have is hiding too many details.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This is a small tweak and probably wont fix your problem, but you might also just want to put `client.close()` in a `finally` block instead of catch (and the main block). This guarantees it's the last thing that happens after any branch in your appliation.

Comment: Also I believe that `client` might not exist in your catch block. Define `client` outside of the try {} scope.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've just added as much as possible - had to simplify though. I added log() after and it and it outputs the same result, but thank you for the recommendation. I added a bit more from the log at the top of the post.

Comment: @DougStevenson I added much more, thanks.

Comment: @Evert Thanks for the recommendation, good to know that it's a best practice. I've now implemented it, but unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem (I defined client outside the try catch as you recommended as well).

Comment: @cubrr Thanks for the recommendation, I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: Don't you have an open firebase connection?  See [How to close firebase connection in nodejs so nodejs will exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38222757/how-to-close-firebase-connection-in-node-js).  Also, I'm not sure you understood that I was suggesting that you use `await` as in `await client.close()` before calling `log()` so you are sure that the client connection has been closed before you do the logging.  `client.close()` is an asynchronous method so your original code would `log()` before that close was complete.

Comment: @jfriend00 well done! Thank you! I am actually using firestore but your recommended concept worked and you're absolutely right, I had an open connection still. I called db.terminate() after awaiting the database sets and it closed everything down properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making my comment into an answer since it led to the missing piece.

Node does not shut down because you have an open Firestore connection.  You will have to call [terminate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Firestore#terminate) to allow the SDK to shut down and release resources:

```
db.terminate();
```

Which is relevant for allowing nodejs to shut itself down automatically.

---

Also, I'm not sure you understood that I was suggesting that you use `await` as in

```
await client.close()
```

before calling `log()` so you are sure that the client connection has been closed before you do the logging. `client.close()` is an asynchronous method so your original code would `log()` before that close was complete.

Comment: The OP's code is using Firestore, not Realtime Database.

Comment: @DougStevenson true but the concept is the same: the connection was open = figure out how to close it. I think it counts as an answer although I 100% agree that putting ```db.terminate()``` would be more accurate than ```firebase.database().goOffline()``` in the answer.

Comment: If you're using Firestore, you should use the code in my answer.

Comment: I would avoid marking this as correct since it might mislead someone in the future.

Comment: @mpc75 - Updated to use terminate.

Comment: It's still linking to unhelpful questions that refer to RTDB.

Comment: @DougStevenson - That's just the article that led us to understand the issue.

Comment: Pretty sure that article does not suggest that you call `db.terminate()` as the answer says. If you're wondering why I'm being persistent about this, it's because people mix up these two databases **all the time** and we don't need any more mixups.  As I'm sure you discovered here.

Comment: @DougStevenson just noticed that you're formerly of Firebase, thanks for your help and expertise as well on this one :)