# Using node the process doesn't exit once finished executing

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, aws-serverless

running code that has a body similar to the one below, the code executes fine, but the connection doesn't close once it's finished, I've looked at [node process doesn't exit after firebase once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046639/node-process-doesnt-exit-after-firebase-once) but I'm looking for something that won't give me an error every time that the function is used in the serverless framework.

```
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var message = {
        notification: {
          title: `**`,
          body: `**`
        },
        condition: `**`
      };
      firebase.messaging().send(message).then((response) => {
        resolve(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          reject(error);
      });
    });
```

How can I get it to exit this process without creating a serverless error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research, and found the way to do this without exiting the AWS serverless function is to use the `firebase.messaging().goOffline()` function instead of the `process.exit()` function

```
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var message = {
        notification: {
          title: `**`,
          body: `**`
        },
        condition: `**`
      };
      firebase.messaging().send(message).then((response) => {
        resolve(response);
        firebase.messaging().goOffline();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          reject(error);
          firebase.messaging().goOffline();
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague, so I might be misunderstanding, but I think you simply need [`process.exit()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) to terminate the Node process.

```js
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var message = {
        notification: {
          title: `**`,
          body: `**`
        },
        condition: `**`
      };
      firebase.messaging().send(message).then((response) => {
        resolve(response);
        process.exit(0) // Addition; zero exit code indicates success
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          reject(error);
          process.exit(1) // Addition; non-zero exit code indicates something went wrong
      });
    });
```