Long delay before completion of a simple firestore-reading script
Getting reoriented after a long time since my last firestore project. Why does this script take an extra 60-90s -- after the output -- to complete? It works properly except for the mysterious ending...
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, collection, query, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";


const firebaseConfig = {
  // my config
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

async function getSomeFirestoreData() {
  try {
    const ref = collection(db, "MyCollection");
    const q = query(ref);
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
    return "done"
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);  // we don't get here
  }
}

getSomeFirestoreData().then(r => {
  console.log(r);  // we get here fast (fast enough)
  process.exit();  // terminates fast with this, but I shouldn't need it
});


After a recent install, package.json:
    "node_modules/@firebase/firestore": {
      "version": "4.6.1",
      ...

I see my doc data after a very reasonable delay and I see "done" immediately. Without the explicit exit, node doesn't terminate for another minute and a half. Why?

Apparently deleting the app might work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046639/node-process-doesnt-exit-after-firebase-once

Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen. deleteApp(app); lets node exit right away (and I guess cleans up politely?).  Needing this seems like either a software or a doc bug.

Yeah, I'm actually not sure how this should detect exit. On JVM we solved this by marking out resource thread as a daemon thread, but I'm not sure how this all works on Node. If you have a good case for it being a bug, I'd recommend filing a bug for that on the repo of the Node Admin SDK.
